# Dual of continuous functions on a compact set with sup norm consists of measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I read the following in Thirring's Quantum Mathematical Physics, 2nd ed., p. 17.

> The dual space of the continuous functions on a compact set, with the norm $\operatorname{sup}_{z\in K} |f(z)|$ consists of the (not necessarily positive) measures on $K$.

$K$ is a compact subset of the complex plane.

Where can I find a reference for the above statement, or how would one go about proving such the above statement? I saw the Wikipedia page on the [Riesz--Markov--Kakutani theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem). In the first version, the space of all continuous compactly supported functions is considered, but the theorem relates positive linear functionals, not all bounded linear functionals, as we need here.  In the second version,  the space considered is the space of continuous functions on a locally compact Hausdorff space which vanish on infinity.

Comment: I found this: https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m511/rieszmarkov.pdf. On the second page under $\textbf{Motivation}$ it constructs the measure for positive linear functionals. Maybe you could see if this can be modified to the more general setting. I know little to nothing about all this. Just thought it might help.

Comment: It's in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 6.19 Page 130.

Comment: @JohnDoe That's it! Thanks for the reference, although Rudin talks about regular Borel measures.